# Handling TCP Data Without a large switch statement

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app that will send and receive data with a TCP socket in IOS using Swift.

I have the communication working fine but what I am trying to do is think of a way to handle the incoming data without a large switch statement.

The app could be sending out various requests at any time but I can't guarantee in what order I will get responses. The first part of each response contains a hex address that tells what information I am receiving is.

I need to take the incoming data and perform a different calculation on it depending on what it is. What I do right now is read the hex address as it comes in and then send it to a giant switch statement which then calles the proper function to convert the data.

I am trying to come up with something better than the giant switch statement. Although I cannot count on exactly what data I will receive in any given message I do know all the possible items that could be received.

Any suggestions that any one has would be appreciated I am not used to handling data like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A giant switch statement is very traditional here. Just make sure to separate your work from your switch. For example, avoid this:

```
switch byte {
    case 0x01:
        doing()
        various()
        things()
    case 0x02:
        doing()
        other()
        things()
    ...
}
```

That code can get pretty messy, though I admit I make this mistake all the time.... The better approach is to pull out the operations:

```
switch byte {
    case 0x01: handleOperationA()
    case 0x02: handleOperationB()
    ...
}

func handleOperationA() { ... }
func handleOperationB() { ... }
```

You of course can make a constants here for 0x01, 0x02, etc., but if this is the *only* place these values, then creating the constant can become duplicative. The name of the function provides just as much documentation as the name of the constant. There are trade-offs here.

Another possibility is to replace your `switch` with a Dictionary, mapping the value to a function (or if it's exactly one byte, and most of the values are used, an Array can even work here, but that's kind of rare).

Dictionaries are nice if things are variable, or if there are a very large number of possible values, but it's not always obvious which is more efficient (the optimizer can do a lot with a switch statement of integers; don't assume dictionary lookups are always faster).

But if you're writing a networking stack, or any kind of parser, embrace a large switch statement. They're completely normal. Just keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback its good to know that I am not doing something completely wrong. I have to say I initially started down the path of your first example but I did catch myself before I got too far along. Thanks again for the feedback.